# How can I connect to a broker using MQTT in MVC framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, mqtt

I'm trying to set up an MQTT connection to a test broker: "test.mosquitto.org" in C# using MVC(this one is just for practise). Eventually I want to make a web application that collects and shows data from databases on different locations. There seem to be no tutorials for MVC framework so I'm following this example: https://gist.github.com/cwschroeder/7b5117dca561c01def041e7d4c6d2771.

The hard part for me is converting that example to MVC framework(with the controllers, models, etc.)

**So I have a few questions about this:**

- Is there a better/easier option for this than MVC?
- What framework is used in the sample?
- What would be my first steps to set up a connecting to a broker in MVC?(also wondering if it would be possible to see an example in code)

I already added some properties and a start + installed the M2mqtt library.
No idea where to go from here. I wish I could just copy paste the sample but that is obviously not possible with MVC.

**MqttClientController**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt;
using uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.Messages;
using uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.Session;
using MvcTestMqtt.Models;


namespace MvcTestMqtt.Controllers
{
    public class MqttClientController : Controller
    {
        // GET: MqttClient
        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult ConnectClient()
        {
            var mqtt = new MqttModel();
            new MqttClient(mqtt.BrokerAddress);
            new MqttClient(mqtt.clientID);
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

**MqttModel:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt;
using uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.Messages;
using MvcTestMqtt.Controllers;


namespace MvcTestMqtt.Models
{
    public class MqttModel
    {
        MqttClient client { get; set; }
        public string clientID { get; set; }
        public string BrokerAddress = "test.mosquitto.org";
    }
}
```

Comment: Asking for examples is off topic for Stack Overflow. Also asking questions about "which is better" only leads to opinion based answers which are again off topic. Please read the guide on how to ask good questions (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and the types of questions to avoid (https://iot.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: Alright but apart from that I'm still asking 3 other questions? can I just delete the asking for examples part then..

Comment: No, none of your questions are on topic